# Origin of the word cron?

Tags: cron, history, conventions

Trying to settle a friendly argument. Is "cron" an acronym for something?

Additionally, did it's current canonical name "cron" originate from something shortened for something like chronos or chronological?

A quick google search didn't find what i was [looking for](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=origin%20of%20cron). It ended up being a forum thread that was [unsettled](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-97446.html)

Comment: χρόνος [chronos] (greek) = time, tabula (latin) = board, Iyyobh [job] (hebrew) = the penitent/hated one

Comment: A quick look into my V7 Unix manual (doesn't everyone have one handy?) shows no such reference, nor have the various papers from the time. Prior to that, you'd have to dig into Multics which referred to batch queues as "absentee computation".

Answer (score 14):

cron derives from Chronos which is a word for time in Greek .

And tab stands for table. You can know that it means a time table.

Answer (score 6):

According to Brian Kernighan, Ken Thompson says he originally wrote it, and that it's an accidental misspelling of the prefix "chrono-" (from Greek χρόνος, chrónos, e.g. as in "chronological"). See [this Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-etymology-of-cron/answer/Kah-Seng-Tay) for more research and context.

[image: Ken Thompson quote: "i wrote it. cron comes from the prefix (greek?) for time. it should have been chron, but i never could spell]

This may be the best we can do, sourcing-wise, as old [V7 man pages](https://www.unix.com/man-page/v7/8/cron/) (as well as 32V and PWB) simply refer to it as "cron - clock daemon", with no further etymology given.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with taffer on likely origins of the command but I think that the only person right now that could definitively answer the question would be [Brian Kernighan](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/) himself

Comment: I think Ritchie or even Pike might know, [Pike](https://plus.google.com/u/0/101960720994009339267)'s on G+ if anyone's interested enough to bother asking him.

Comment: @bdowning [Dennis Ritchie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dennis_Ritchie) passed away late last year

Comment: Yeah, I knew that. I meant Kernighan, though again, Pike is the one with a G+ acct.